# GORM not saving record to association table from CONSOLE

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
class Pirate {
    String name
    static belongsTo = Ship
    static hasMany = [ships: Ship]
}

class Ship {
    String name
    static hasMany = [crew: Pirate]
}

new Ship(name: "Ship1").addToCrew(new Pirate(name: "pirate1")).save()
```

The above code is only saving an entry in the `Pirate` and `Ship` table but not in the `ship_crew` table.

I'm aware of [this technique](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/templates/PersonAuthority.groovy.template) used by Burt in the Spring Security Grails plugin but I'd still like to be able to use the `hasMany` and `belongsTo`

**UPDATE**

The above line of code seems to be saving the entries in all three: `Pirate`, `Ship`, and `ship_crew` table, however, from the console it only saves entries in the two tables and not in `ship_crew`

```
> new Ship(name: "Ship10").addToCrew(new Pirate(name: "pirate10")).save(failOnError:true) 
new Ship(name: "Ship10").addToCrew(new Pirate(name: "pirate10")).save(failOnError:true) 
Hibernate: 
    /* insert playwithgrails.Ship
        */ insert 
        into
            ship
            (version, name) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert playwithgrails.Pirate
        */ insert 
        into
            pirate
            (version, name) 
        values
            (?, ?)
===> playwithgrails.Ship : 29
```

Comment: i created a test web app (with your domain models and a basic test controller with your statement) and it saved successfully all the entities including the assoc

Comment: So weird. It works from a sample controller for me as well but doesn't work from the grails console

Comment: could you try to save with the failOnError parameter equals to true like this:
new Ship(name: "Ship1").addToCrew(new Pirate(name: "pirate1")).save(failOnError:true)

Comment: please see my update. It is still saving only to two tables...Can you try in your sample app whether you have the same issue?